# Why the community of two subspace is not necessarily a whole space of the set R?

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

If W1 and W2 are the subspace of W, prove that

(a): The Intersection of W1 and W2 is a subspace of W

(b): The community of W1 and W2 may not necessarily be subspace W

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Community? You mean union? Then you're right.

Answer (score 0):

For instance, consider two lines in the 2D or 3D real space; a line is a 1D-subspace.

If the lines are distinct, the intersection is given by the zero point $\{0\}$ which is a 0D-subspace.
The union of two distinct lines is not a subspace. The smallest subspace containing these lines is the plane (2D-space) generated by the two lines.

Comment: Thank you. I need to prove it in algebra notation. can you give a help.